# How to detect tapping on the gray (dimmed) background in UISearchDisplayController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am working on a iOS project where I want to implement a search functionality. I'm using `UISearchBar` and `UISearchDisplayController` and I would like to make `UISearchBar` implicitly hidden. When user taps on the `UIBarButtonItem`, the search bar will appear and "becomeFirstResponder", whereas when user clicks on the `Cancel` button in the search bar, it should disappear.

The appearing is working correctly, but I have a problem with disappearing. I managed to hide the search bar when user taps on the `Cancel` button (`searchBarCancelButtonClicked` method), but I'm unable to hide the search bar when the grey (dimmed) background in `UISearchDisplayController` is tapped. As far as I know, there is no method to detect this event, so it is necessary to apply some hack. Do you know any, or what is the best way to detect tapping on the gray background?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I've finally worked it out. Apart from the `searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar`, it is also necessary to hide the search bar in `searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller`. It looks this callback is called even when the gray (dimmed) background is tapped, so it can be easily used for hiding the search bar.

Answer (score 0):

UISearchDisplayController usually consists of a UISegmentedControl, the UIResultsTable and the keyboard. The results table is where you want to detect this touch to dismiss. With that being known, maybe you can add a transparent UIButton to that view that dismisses first responder, or Maybe you can add a UIGestureRecognizer on a transparent view that achieves the same effect? Just thinking off the top and have not tried this myself, if it works for you im glad !

Comment: I think UIResultsTable is not what I'm looking for. Results table is displayed only after typing into the search bar. Before this, there is no UITableView there, just a gray background.